# How to resize to fullscreen when touched the view that in TabBarController based app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

Here're some view controller I have: **tabBarController**, **navigationBarController**, **viewController**, and **imageView**.
The hierarchy is that: **tabBarController** is the root controller, it includes **navigationBarController**. And the **viewController**(which is include the **imageView**) is pushed in by **navigationBarController**.

So the question is, when I touched the **imageView**, how to resize it to fullscreen with smooth animation. Note, I don't want to hide NavigationBar & TabBar.
I tried it by `setFrame`, however, it is covered by **navigationBarController** and **tabBarController**.
I tried `presentModalViewController:` but it lose continuity.
I also tried to reset `rootViewController` to **viewController**, but the resulted with a broken animation. :(
Thanks for any suggestion!

---

### Test code

```
UIViewController * viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[viewController.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];

UIViewController * anotherTabViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[anotherTabViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[anotherTabViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, anotherTabViewController, nil];
[navigationController release];
[anotherTabViewController release];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Here I write a simple code for testing. Now don't care about the touch action. I wonder how to set the imageView to totally fullscreen(width:320, height:480). But it's clipped by navigation bar and tab bar. I know the frame is relative to its super view. How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add img to you window, when you need to resize it to full screen:

```
    UIImageView *img; //create new image
    img = yourImageView;
    [img setOrigin:CGPointMake(yourImageView.frame.origin.x, yourImageView.frame.origin.y+90)]; 
//window size is bigger, so to set an image frame visionary at same place, you need to set origin point lower
    MOEAppDelegate *sharedAppDelegate = (MOEAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [sharedAppDelegate.window addSubview:img];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                     animations:^{
                         [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                                                  0, 
                                                  320, 
                                                  480)];
                     }];
```

Note, that your self.view's frame automatically resized when you adding tabBar or navigationBar, and in -(void)viewDidLoad it is NOT resized jet!

Comment: Hi @SentineL, thanks for your replay. But I tried it. The view is pushed by navigation controller, it's covered by navigation bar. And when I set the image to fullscreen, its max frame size is equal to the view's. Setting the view's frame automatically resized? I'm not sure if it'll works, I'll try. Thanks. :)

Comment: I print the `viewContrller`'s view frame, that is `0, 0, 320, 346`(NavigationBar's height is 90, TabBar's height is 44).

Comment: may be your image is NOT a viewController's view subview? try this: [self.view addSubView:img]; then, set frame. Note, thet you need addSubView only ONE time.

Comment: Yes it is the subview of the viewController.view.

Comment: you should post some code. there is a mistake somewhere alse. If your viewController's view has frame 0, 0, 320, 346, then image MUST be in it.

Comment: oh... so, you need the image to be above tab bar and nav. bar? I just didn't get it earlyer.

Comment: Ya! That's what I want. Thorny issue.. :(

Comment: Thanks @SentineL Well, I did try it. But now as the imageView is not the viewControllerView's subview, it'll not transition with viewControllerView(Actually it is a scrollView). Shall I change the subView when do animation?

Comment: you should animate NEW image. not old, the one (that in your scroll view). By the way, your scroll view will make "y" correction of new image pretty hard. So: you have scroll view with images. user tap image, image become full-screen. Image hides all controlls. user tap it one more time, it becomes small, controlls become avalible. User can navigate in the app now. Right?

Comment: Yes it is! I'm still trying. I tried to get old image's frame data to set the new image to the same, then do animation with `[UIView animation ...`. But the effect works not very well.

Comment: use ScrollView.contentOffset to calculate image's position

Comment: Thank you for giving your time, let me try. :)